# iOS App: playing mp4 file from mainBundle crashes

Tags: ios, file, mp4

I am trying to play test.mp4 from inside my App, but it crashes with the following error:

```
2013-06-28 15:02:40.931 framing[9617:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1a5f012 0x176ce7e 0x1a5edeb 0x11839b1 0x118393b 0x28c2 0x1780705 0x6b42c0 0x6b4258 0x775021 0x77557f 0x7746e8 0x6e3cef 0x6e3f02 0x6c1d4a 0x6b3698 0x2ac1df9 0x2ac1ad0 0x19d4bf5 0x19d4962 0x1a05bb6 0x1a04f44 0x1a04e1b 0x2ac07e3 0x2ac0668 0x6b0ffc 0x223d 0x2165)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

The following are the codes:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize moviePlayer,movieScreen,viewVideoTitleBg;

-(IBAction)playTheMovie {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mp4"];
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController
                    alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
    //[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(64,192,895,415);
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    //[moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
    [moviePlayer play];
}
```

I have got the Frameworks installed too.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: apparently, the following line keeps returning nill value for the 'path'.     NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mp4"];
Could someone please help me solving this?

Comment: Are you sure that you have the test.mp4 file in your resource?

Comment: The answer to this is ensuring that the Target Dependency of the video file is set to the project

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this issue recently. My work around was to delete the video file from the bundle and drag-drop it again.

Clean and build and then run it again.

But for instance: You should check the spelling and capitalisation of the name of the video file and the one used in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [NSURL URLWithString : path]; instead of [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

Answer (score 0):

check if this

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mp4"]
```

return nil.
if this return nil, you need to add the mp4 file to xcode project and SELECT  >ADD TO TARGET< checkbox.